# How can I get the TopicIDs from a CHM file?

Tags: chm, sandcastle, excel-dna

I am generating a CHM file with Sandcastle Help File Builder, based on a ***csproj*** file. What I'm ultimately trying  to do, is to find the TopicID of each topic in the CHM file, and use them with Excel-Dna like so:

```
...
[ExcelFunction(Category = "MyCategory", Name = "MyUDF", HelpTopic="MyHelp.chm!102")]
...
```

Even though I know all the URLs for the articles in the CHM file -- I can see the contents with 7zip and HTML Help Workshop (HHW) -- I don't know how to use Sandcastle or HHW to map the topics to certain ids or to find out the ids of the topics I already have.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Christos

----UPDATE ----

I went ahead and created a CHM file with Doxygen, and manually added the [MAP] and [ALIAS] fields in the HPP file in HTML Help Workshop. I've mapped a specific html to the number 1000, so now when I use "MyHelp.chm!1000", it actually opens the right html inside the chm file.
Hence I think it's an issue with Sandcastle not doing the mapping and the aliasing for use with Excel-Dna. I don't want to do this roundabout way, as I was planning on adding this as a build event on the TFS we use.
Do you think there's any other way?

I've tried to do this:

```
MyHelp.chm!html\filename_of_generated_html
MyHelp.chm!html\filename_of_generated_html.html
MyHelp.chm!html\\filename_of_generated_html
MyHelp.chm!html.filename_of_generated_html
```

But none of them seem to be able to point into the CHM file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've realised there doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this automatically. The best compromise, of time and effort put into this, is to create a map/alias file to do a re-mapping. By using the output that SHFB creates as an interim by-product you can inject a custom made HHP file that includes all the mappings and aliases for each HTML file. Then it's just a matter of compiling everything again with the said HHP file. When a new UDF function is added to the Excel front-end and exposed via Excel-Dna, manual entries need to be added to the HHP file. For a project with a few UDFs I think it's not worth the effort to automatically create the HHP file. If however you are dealing with 1000's of UDFs you might be better off creating a C# project to automatically generate this file.
So when a new UDF function is created the following lines will need to be added to the HHP file:

```
 For example if you've created the UDF function MyFunction(...), then its Excel-Dna attribute
 will be: 
 [ExcelFunction(IsThreadSafe = true, Category = Defines.ExcelCategory, Name = "MyFunction", Description = "My function's description", HelpTopic = "Help_Manual.chm!XXXX")]

 Then you'll need to add the following lines in the HHP file:

 [FILES]
 ...
 html\M_ExcelWrapper_QDAExcelUDFs_MyFunction.htm
 ...    


 [ALIAS]
 ...
 MYFUNCTION=html\M_ExcelWrapper_ExcelUDFs_MyFunction.htm
 ...     


 [MAP]
 ...
 #DEFINE MYFUNCTION                     XXXX
 ...
```

The name of the Mapping needs to match the alias assignement, which in turn needs to point to a file already added in the [Files] section.

I hope this is useful somehow.